# How to disable databound TextBox(s) using for next

Tags: vb.net

The code give below disables only non-databound textbox(s).

```
Private Sub DisableFields()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (ctrl) Is TextBox Then
            CType(ctrl, TextBox).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I disable databound textbox(s)?

Comment: Are you sure that your textboxes to be disabled are directly in the form controlcollection? If they are childs of a groupbox or panel or other containers they are not disabled with this loop.

Comment: Just to understand, it is for a WinForm project or Wpf one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to do it.
You should go into the xaml of each TextBox and bind IsEnabled to a property (expl : AllowEdit) that you put in your View Model / Code Behind.
This property must raise NotifyPropertyChanged.
You can even set it as default behaviour of the TextBox, by setting the binding in a Style or in the default Style, and if you need to override here or there you can set IsEnabled="true".

EDIT : 
to loop through all available TextBox, you need to use the VisualTreeHelper to walk
the visual tree :

```
  Public Sub ApplyOnAllDescendant(ByVal BaseUIElement As UIElement, 
                                      ByVal TargetType As Type, 
                                             ByVal NewIsEnabled As Boolean)
    If BaseUIElement Is Nothing Then Return
    If BaseUIElement.GetType() = TargetType Then
        BaseUIElement.IsEnabled = NewIsEnabled
    Else
        Dim ChildCount As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(BaseUIElement)
        For i = 0 To ChildCount - 1
            ApplyOnAllDescendant(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(BaseUIElement, i), 
                                           TargetType, NewIsEnabled)
        Next
    End If
  End Sub
```

that you call with :

```
      ApplyOnAllDescendant(Me, GetType(TextBox), False)
```

if you want to know if there's a binding, you could use

```
Dim Bindings = CType(BaseUIElement, Control)
                                 .GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)
```

and then look the content of Bindings.

But again, this is not a 'clean' way to do it.

Comment: Disabling like this works: databoundtextbox.enabled=false. So vincent could you please tell me for my knowledge as to why for next will not work?

Comment: i wrote a little sub to explain how to do it in wpf

Comment: Pretty complicated! Could I code each and every textbox's condition in a module and then call it?

Comment: i don't quite see how you could do that. The right way to go is to have a Property as i told in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Steve, as you have so rightly asked me; the TextBox(s) are inserted on top of a group box. Removing the group box, I can now disable the TextBox(s). Thanks a mil! Vincent, I hope to learn wpf someday, but would it be so complicated! Thanking you all for your kind support.